# Google Authentication Endless Loop

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

My app.js looks like this:

```
// Initialize Firebase
    const config = {
        apiKey: //...
        authDomain: //...
        databaseURL: //...
        storageBucket://...
        messagingSenderId: //...
     };
     firebase.initializeApp(config);

}());

    function.googleSignin(){
        var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
        firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider);
    }

    firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
  // This gives you a Google Access Token. You can use it to access the Google API.
        var token = result.credential.accessToken;
  // The signed-in user info.
        var user = result.user;
  // ...
}).catch(function(error) {
  // Handle Errors here.
      var errorCode = error.code;
      var errorMessage = error.message;
  // The email of the user's account used.
      var email = error.email;
  // The firebase.auth.AuthCredential type that was used.
      var credential = error.credential;
  // ...
});
```

However, now when I load my page, it automatically redirects to google sign in (for now, I only want them to be redirected to login upon clicking the button). More importantly, it does this in an endless loop: redirecting me to the login page after I've already logged in.

What do I need to do so that it only redirects when the button is clicked? And doesn't automatically redirect to google login afterwards?

===========================================================================
I'm very new to web development and am totally lost as how to integrate google sign in my app that is hosted on Firebase. I have created a pop-up that has a google sign in button.

```
               <div id="id01" class="modal">
               <form class="modal-content animate" action="action_page.php">
                   <div class="imgcontainer">
                       <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
                        </div>
                       <div class="loginMsg">
                           <p>hi there!</p>
                           <p>log in to post and comment on ride share</p>
                       </div>
                       <button class="loginBtn loginBtn--facebook">connect with facebook</button>
                       <button class="loginBtn loginBtn--google">connect with google     </button>
                </form>
           </div>
```

I'm trying to understand the [Firebase instructions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin), but I'm lost. Where in my code do I execute these steps? For instance, do I include "var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();" in a script in my index.html page? In app.js? Of course I need my button to redirect to this login feature, so how would I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can't call signInWithRedirect and getRedirectResult in the same button click callback.

Typically, here is what you can do:

For your button on click handler, do the following:

```
function.googleSignin(){
  var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
  firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider);
}
```

Outside of your function set redirect listener:

```
firebase.auth().getRedirectResult().then(function(result) {
  if (result.user) {
    // User just signed in. you can get the result.credential.
    // Update your UI, hide the sign in button.
  } else if (firebase.auth().currentUser) {
    // User already signed in.
    // Update your UI, hide the sign in button.
  } else {
    // No user signed in, update your UI, show the sign in button.
  }
});
```